# Calling a Managed-C#-DLL from Unity is very slow

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dll

I am currently working on an Unity Projekt. My idea of the projects general structure was the following: Defining all possible "GameObjects" in a Dll and use Unity-Classes as Wrappers for these classes with additional Rendering Stuff, etc.
So that the Dll-Classes can be used in a Console Applikation and unity is one of many possible renderers.

The problem that occurs is, that calling functions that are implemented in the Dll seems to be very slow. Take a look at the following example: If i call the `CalculateSomething()`-Function directly from a Console-Application-Project, it will take about 2ms to get the job done. 
When called from Unity it ranges between 14ms and 30ms.

Are there any obvious mistakes or misconceptions I've made? Note, that the Dll-Function gets called on every frame so some sort of Dll lazy-loading shouldn't be an issue? I'm glad for every hint or help! Thanks in advance!

Here is the Unity Part:

```
class UnityClass : DllInterface
{
    DllInterface object;

    void Update()
    {
        //This call is very slow
        int[] returnValues = CalculateSomething();
        //Do something with these values.
    }

    int[] CalculateSomething()
    {
        return object.CalculateSomething();
    }
}
```

And then in the Dll-Project:

```
DllClass : DllInterface
{
    public int[]CalculateSomething()
    {
        //Computation gets done here.
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are in Unity, I guess that each frame is timed ? there could be  some idle triggered by your animation ? :)

Comment: So what can I do to check or solve this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know It was just a suggestion on how to explain, I never worked on Unity3D :) But suggestion, is to use some metrics tool, to see how long you spend in object.calculatesomething :-)

Comment: It looks like, that the full time is spent inside the Dll. But why is the Dll function that much faster when called from a Console Application?

Comment: So [here:](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/325710/dll-call-10x-slower-in-unity.html) someone had the same problem, however the question dates back to 2012. One hint was, that it has something to do with garbage collection being different between Unity and C#. Any clues left about how I can profile/find out what is going on?